# Support which version of python when packaging?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, packaging

I am writing a package and its compatible with 2.7 and the latest 3.6.
(support of 2.7 is planned to be removed ;)).

1. Is there a best practice regarding which version to support? For obvious reasons, I do not really want to have my CI running on every python versions...
2. I often see in requirements: python 2.7 and >3.3.
   Why is that and not just python >2.7?

Comment: For 2, it's because Python 3.3 reinstated support for the `u` prefix for strings, which was missing from 3.0-3.2, see [PEP0414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/).

Comment: oh OK I was expecting a bit more.